# thoughts on this log - log plot ?suitable for cox proportional hazards model

Tags: hazard

I'm quite new at using the cox proportional hazards model and was wondering if someone can please offer some advice on whether this log - log plot shows whether proportional hazards assumption has been violated or not?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a systematically decreasing hazard ratio so I'd guess that PH is being violated enough to matter.  You can plot a smoothed scaled Schoenfeld residual plot and get an associated PH test if you want further evidence.

Try to see if an accelerated failure time model that assumes a diminishing hazard ratio that eventually converges to 1.0 fits your data.  To check a log-normal model change the $y$-axis to the normal inverse of Kaplan-Meier estimates and $x$ to $\log(t)$.  Look for parallelism.

A different approach would be more honest in the sense of providing the right uncertainties for p-values and confidence intervals while fitting the data very well: add a time-dependent covariate for group $\times t$ interaction so that group requires 2 coefficients.  The approach of trying different distributions such as what I suggested above will result in some hidden model uncertainty that makes standard errors too small.

Comment: Many thanks, that makes sense. I presume the issue is the tail end of the graph where sample size numbers are very low (less than 10% remaining from total at start). does this affect things given this information?

Comment: Yes  but the sample sizes there can't be too low because the curves are so smooth there.